# Is there a function equivalent for $sformat?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm writing SystemVerilog code and I notice that $sformat is a system task, not a function.
Is there a function equivalent to $sformat?

I'd like to do the following inside a function:

```
assert(my_dto_h.a == 10) else begin
  `ovm_error("component", $sformat("my_dto_h.a should be 10, not %0d", my_dto_h.a))
end
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the the following run-time error from QuestaSim 10.2:

`** Error: (vsim-PLI-3029) component.sv(105): Expected a system function, not system task '$sformat'.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `$sformatf`

From the LRM:

> The system function `$sformatf` behaves like `$sformat` except that the string result is passed back as the function result value for `$sformatf`, not placed in the first argument as for `$sformat`. Thus `$sformatf` can be used where a string value would be valid.

```
variable_format_string_output_function ::=
   $sformatf ( format_string [ , list_of_arguments ] )
```

Example:

```
string s;
s = $sformatf("Value = %0d", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$psprintf`. It is not part of the standard, but many simulators such as QuestaSim and VCS support it.

```
assert(my_dto_h.a == 10) else begin
  `ovm_error("component", $psprintf("my_dto_h.a should be 10, not %0d", my_dto_h.a))
end
```